# @OneToOne on primary keys of tables not working while insert

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have below two tables having uni-directional relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`partition_key` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`partition_key`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `document_payload` (
`document_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`document_payload` mediumtext,
`partition_key` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`document_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

so here document_id column of document_payload refers to id column of document. Now I wanted to join these two tables in my model class, below way:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonSnakeCase
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Document {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String partitionKey;

@OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "document_id")
private DocumentPayload documentPayload;

@NotNull
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

@PrePersist
public void onCreate() {
    createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

}

and

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonSnakeCase
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DocumentPayload {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "document_id")
private Long documentId;

private String documentPayload;

private String partitionKey;
```

}

But while persisting, it is throwing following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'document_id' doesn't have a default value
```

I tried @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn the way I am using @joincolumn but no help, I want to propagate auto-generated value of id to dcoument_payload table as document_id, what am I missing here?

Comment: how do you persist your entities?

Comment: Using EntityManager's persist method. this.getEntityManager.persist(document)

Comment: can you share the code for that

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Db fault: you simply forgot AUTO_INCREMENT declaration

```
CREATE TABLE `document_payload` (
`document_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`document_payload` mediumtext,
`partition_key` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`document_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

You need that since you are using `IDENTITY` as autogeneration type

Answer (score 0):

```
`id`          bigint(20)       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`document_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

DATATYPE must be consistent (excluding `NULL` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`).

Answer (score 0):

In `Document.documentPayload` you should use another column name than `id`, as it's already mapped for `Document.id` property, also it's not necessary to use [referencedColumnName](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName()) as you're mapping the primary key of `DocumentPayload` entity, the documentation states that by default it presents :

> The same name as the primary key column of the referenced table.

So `Document` class will be :

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonSnakeCase
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Document {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String partitionKey;

@OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_document_id") // you can use whatever name you want unless it's already used for this table.  
private DocumentPayload documentPayload;

@NotNull
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

@PrePersist
public void onCreate() {
    createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

Just to note that you should not implement the setter for auto generated id property, coz once it's generated it should not be changed, and I suggest to add `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` (in the field declaration), and  [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) won't generate the setter method.